# How to Post layer of Openlayer to the GeoServer using GeoServer Rest API?

Tags: rest, gis, openlayers-3, geoserver

I am using Openlayer 3 at the client side to add raster and vector layer to the map.

Now i want to post this layer(OpenLayer object) on the GeoServer using Rest Api from the client side.

Does anyone has any idea how  can i implement this?

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: are you planning on giving users your admin password? If not you need to rethink this plan, may be WFS-T and WCS-T?

Comment: @iant We have  our own server between between client and geoserver, So every request go through the server therefore we can manage admin password. And i am also open to WFS-T and WCS-T.